# How to have div re-size itself to image on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

So my goal is to have an image slideshow with 3 clickable hot spots at the bottom. I have the basic functionality of this down now, but my content div doesn't size itself properly until it loops through the images for the first time. I need everything to be sized and positioned correctly immediately when the page loads.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">     
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#image").attr("src", images[0]);         
        });     

        //Click tracking
        var badClicks = 0;
        var skipClicks = 0;
        var goodClicks = 0;

        //Counter to keep track of images
        var iCount = 0;
        var images = [];
        images[0] = "images/document.png";
        images[1] = "images/document2.png";
        images[2] = "images/document3.png";

        function nextImage(){
            iCount++;

            //If there are no more images in the array, go back to the first image
            if (images[iCount]==null) {
                iCount = 0;
            };

            //Change image source to new image
            $("#image").attr("src", images[iCount]);

            //Set content wrapper width & height to current image's width & height
            $("#content").css("width", $("#image").css("width"));
            $("#content").css("height", $("#image").css("height"));

            //Store content wrapper's new width and height into variables
            var h = parseInt($("#content").css("height"));
            var w = parseInt($("#content").css("width"));

            //Move hotspot-wrapper to the bottom of the new image
                //Height of content wrapper - height of hotspot wrapper = new top
            $("#hotspot-wrapper").css("top", h - parseInt($("#hotspot-wrapper").css("height")));


            console.log(images[iCount] + " h " + h + " w " + w);
        }

        //Do something with data for "bad" hotspot
        function bad(){
            badClicks++;
        }

        //Do something with data for "skip" hotspot
        function skip(){
            skipClicks++;
            nextImage();
        }

        //Do something with data for "good" hotspot
        function good(){
            goodClicks++;
        }

        //Show the collected data
        function displayResults(){
            $("#results").append("<br />Bad: " + badClicks 
            + " Skip: " + skipClicks 
            + " Good: " + goodClicks);
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">      
        <img id="image" />
        <div id="hotspot-wrapper">
            <div id="hotspot-a" class="hotspot" onclick="bad();"></div>
            <div id="hotspot-b" class="hotspot" onclick="skip();"></div>
            <div id="hotspot-c" class="hotspot" onclick="good();"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <br />
        <div id="results" style="clear:both">
            <button onclick="displayResults();" style="text-align: center">Show results</button>
        </div>
```

Any help, tips or advice would be greatly appreciated! 
Thanks!

Comment: The images aren't loaded yet when you attempt to get their width/height. You should preload them.

Comment: Have you considered setting everything to visibility:hidden until window.load() triggers?

Comment: try pre loading the images, or setting an image tag for each image and just set there viability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your problem

```
 $("#image").css("width")
```

However, you havent set #image's width with css. You need to use

```
$('#image').width()
```

Also, to be safe, you should only continue with this part of the code AFTER your image has triggered a load event:

```
//Change image source to new image
$("#image").attr("src", images[iCount]).load(function(){

    //Set content wrapper width & height to current image's width & height
    $("#content").css("width", $("#image").width());
    $("#content").css("height", $("#image").height());

    //And then the rest...
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all i prefer this way to init images array:

```
var images = [];
var image = new Image();
image.src = '/some/image/url.jpg';
/* while you doing this image already load in background - so its faster way*/
images.push(image);
```

You can display this images with jQuery this way:

```
$('#parend_of_image_div').html(images[iCount]);
```

And inside your `nextImage` function use this code:

```
var img = images[iCount];
$(img).load(function(){
    var width = $(this).width()
    var height = $(this).height();
    /* do other stuff */
});
```

Comment: I will definitely keep that snippet written down!